# R Shiny Refresh App Keep Same Tab

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have the Shiny app remember which tab was selected at the time of a `session$reload()` (refreshing the page) to clear all inputs **except** the value of the current tab selected in a `navbarPage()`.

The only idea that comes to mind, though I don't know how I could implement this, would be to assign a global variable `tabIndicator` as the value of the current tab selected (how do you get this value?), then on refresh, `rm()` all variables in global environment except `tabIndicator`, and set `selected = tabIndicator` in `navbarPage()`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using a global variable.

I put this code at the top of my app (before `ui` and `server`)

```
# Clear global environment except 'currentTab'
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), 'currentTab'))

# If current tab exists, restore to that tab. Otherwise, start at home screen
if(!exists('currentTab')){
  currentTab <- 'HOMEPAGE'
}
```

And this code at the bottom of my `server`

```
# Current tab
observe({
  currentTab <<- input$navbar
})
```

Works like a charm. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: As a note, what this does is essentially remember which tab was selected when the tab last closed. If you want this to work **only** for refresh, you may need to assign another global variable and have more if/else branching.

Comment: This solution also means that ALL users will share the same tab. If I go to your app and open a specific tab, then you go to the app on your computer 2 seconds later, you'll be on the tab that I opened. I don't know if that's the behaviour you wanted, it's usually not a desired behaviour.

Comment: That's true. For my purposes, all users of my app work from their own computer, which means this is less of an issue. But that is a great point that this is usually not desired behavior, and for others, this may not be quite good enough. However I do not know anything about HTML5 or using cookies, so this will need to work for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, both are beyond the basics of shiny.

1. You could use cookies. Every time a new tab is entered, send a message to javascript and set a cookie. When the app initializes, check for the presence of the cookie, and if it's set then read its value and change to the appropriate tab
2. Use the [shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore) package, which gives you the ability of leveraging HTML5's local storage (but this won't work on older browsers because HTML5 is relatively new)

I don't have time to provide full code right now, but hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, I think, but tricky. The issue is that `session$reload()` is equivalent to hitting the refresh button in the browser, so you're creating a new session, and losing all of the context. I guess you could use cookies somehow to do it, but I'd recommend using an `actionButton` that resets all of your inputs using `updateWhatever`, instead of actually doing the `session$reload()`.

Comment: Could an `actionButton` be programmed to not only clear all inputs but outputs too? For example, output table objects?