# Reload a page and switch to tab

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I use the package `shinyjs` to allow the user to reload the page by clicking on "Reload the page" button in Tab 2 and I would like to stay on Tab 2 after reloading the page. But after realoading, the page is taking to Tab1 instead of Tab2

How can we fix it ? This is my code below :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "shinyjs.refresh = function() { history.go(0); }"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = "refresh"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", actionButton("mybutton", "Reload the page", 
                                   onclick ="javascript:window.location.reload(true)")))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use global variable if your app is meant to go on local computers , or cookies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687459/r-shiny-refresh-app-keep-same-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resort to plain `JavaScript`. The idea is that you provide an `id` to  `tabsetPanel` such that you can use `updateTabsetPanel` in the server.

All you have to do then is to let the reloaded page know that you want to start on the second tab. As a refresh typically resets all of the inputs and reactives (**you are aware of that, right?**), you cannot use `reactives` and you have to rely on another way of communication. The query string would be one possibility.

With these ingredients you can:

1. Write a simple `JavaScript` function that reloads the page and adds a parameter to the url.
2. Parse the query string in the server and if the parameter is found, react on it accordingly.

```r
library(shiny)

js <- HTML("
           function doReload(tab_index) {
              let loc = window.location;
              let params = new URLSearchParams(loc.search);
              params.set('tab_index', tab_index);
              loc.replace(loc.origin + loc.pathname + '?' + params.toString());
           }")

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(tags$script(js, type ="text/javascript")),
   tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", value = "tab1"),
      tabPanel("Tab 2", value = "tab2", 
               actionButton("mybutton", "Reload the page", 
                            onclick = "doReload('tab2')")),
      id = "tabsets"
      
   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observe({
      params <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
      if ("tab_index" %in% names(params)) {
         updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabsets", selected = params$tab_index)   
      }
   })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The same can be done using basic shiny (no additonal JS needed) - for those interested please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715897/shiny-how-to-remember-user-input-after-click-on-refresh/72716172#72716172).